# Mono dynamic LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c#, linux, mono, shared-libraries

I've got the following directory structure in my bin directory:

```
appdir
-lib
--bin
---unix
----x64
----x86
```

I'm running my mono app on linux. 
Is it somehow possible to load the libraries dynamic depending on the platform and the architecture?

Or is it possible to make the dllmap relative to the output directory?

Yet I've only managed to call the app via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ mono MyApp.exe`

**NOTE:** I'm talking about native shared object libraries.

Comment: Did you try to use AssemblyResolve event? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've forgot to mention that I'm talking about shared object libraries (native assemblies not managed).

Comment: Ok, what if just set LD_LIBRARY_PATH from application itself, right after startup? There you already know architecture and platform, and no native calls are made yet.

Comment: That won't work. The value of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is read out once at the start of the application.

Comment: You are right. What about using dll maps (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllmap/)? They allow to specify os and arcitecture for your DllImports.

Comment: I'm using those. But they don't allow relative paths to the application directory.